# Angular - Execute code only after all subscribes are finished inside for loop

Tags: angular

Below is my code

```
    if(this.customAttributes.length > 0){
        this.isErrorMessage = false;
        let errcounter = 0;
        for( let i=0; i<this.customAttributes.length; i++) {
          let customAttr = [];
          customAttr.push(this.customAttributes[i]);
          this.customFieldsService.saveCustomFieldsData(customAttr).subscribe((res: any) => {
            if(res && Array.isArray(res)) {
              this.ngxSpinner.hide();              
              const items = res.filter(item => item.errorCode !== null);
              if(items.length > 0 ){
                this.isErrorMessage = true;
                errcounter++;
              } else {
                this.isErrorMessage = false; 
              }
            }         
          }); 
        } 

        if(errcounter > 0) {
          console.log('errors in page');
        } else { 
          this.getCustomFieldsData(); 
        }
    }
```

Here what I am trying to do is, calling the service method `saveCustomFieldsData` in for loop which will give response for each request.

And, I am checking whether any of the response is containing `errorCode`. If `errorCode` is present in the response I am using a counter `errcounter`.

So, finally I need to call another method `getCustomFieldsData` only when there is no `errorCode` returned by the API.

But, what happening with my code is, the `if(errcounter > 0) {` is not waiting until the `for` loop completes. Can some body please suggest what changes do I need to make here to wait until the loop finishes and then execute the `if` condition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use RxJs forkJoin.

Comment: And here is the [link to forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin). It is intended exactly for this use case.